# Socket OSError: [WinError 10022]

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to scan ip's subnet using socket lib on python3.7.6, but it throws OSError.

**Stacktrace**

```
  File "scanny.py", line 88, in scanSubnet
    self.session.connect((host, 497))
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

**CODE**

**Class' __init__**

```
def __init__(self, openedPorts=[], timeout=0.1):
    self.host = '#!' #default value
    self.port = '#!'
    self.portRange = '#!'
    self.openedPorts = openedPorts
    self.noGAIerror = True
    self.session = s.socket()
    self.session.settimeout(timeout)
```

**Problematic code**

```
def scanSubnet(self):
    hosts=[]
    cp("\tIP: ", color="green", end='') #termcolor's cprint
    host = input()
    i = 1
    while i <= 256:
        host = str(host[:-len(str(i-1))] + str(i-1))
        cp(host,color="yellow")
        try:
            self.session.connect((host, 497))
            cp("\n\t[" + host + "] OK",color="green")
            hosts.append(host)
            self.session.close()
            self.__init__()
        except s.timeout: pass # s = socket
        except s.gaierror: continue
```

How can I avoid this?